# Creating a text file with a timestamp in the title

Tags: c++, timestamp, text-files, fstream, datestamp

I'm trying to write a program which outputs a lot of data in separate text files. I want the title of each file to be *Poker_Log_timestamp_datestamp.txt*
However, it doesn't actually create the file, nor does it throw any errors!

Here's the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char sdate[9];
    char stime[9];
    fstream log;
    _strdate_s(sdate);
    _strtime_s(stime);
    string filename = "Poker_Log_";
    filename.append(stime);
    filename.append("_");
    filename.append(sdate);
    filename.append(".txt");
    cout<<"Filename == "<<filename<<endl;
    log.open(filename.c_str());
    log<<"\n\nHuman won the tournament.\n";
    log.close();
    system("Pause");
}
```

How do I make this work?
One other thing: If I comment out `filename.append(stime)` and `filename.append(sdate)`, it works fine.

SOLVED :D The file name cant have any slashes or colons, so i replaced them both with dashes. Here is the working code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char sdate[9];
    char stime[9];
    ofstream log;
    _strdate_s(sdate);
    _strtime_s(stime);
    string filename = "Poker_Log_";
    filename.append(stime);
    filename.append("_");
    filename.append(sdate);
    filename.append(".txt");
    for(int i = 0; i<filename.length(); ++i){
        if (filename[i] == '/' || filename[i] == ':')
            filename[i] = '-';
    }
    log.open(filename.c_str());
    if (log.fail())
        perror(filename.c_str());

    log<<"\n\nHuman won the tournament.\n";
    log.close();
    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: I don't know what these `_strdate_s` and `_strtime_s` functions are, but if the `cout << ...` line immediately before `log.open` prints what you expect it to print, then your problem is *not* with the construction of the filename.  You're not checking for errors in `log.open` -- fstreams do *not* (by default) signal failure by throwing an exception.  If you add `if (log.fail()) perror(filename.c_str());` immediately after the `log.open` line, what does it print?  (May need to add `#include <cstdio>` for that to compile.)

Comment: It says "Poker_log_17:18:13_03/01/13.txt: Invalid Arguement.
I thought maybe the '/'s were confusing it, so i removed the date, but it says the same thing about the time-only version.

Comment: Colons may be a problem, too, depending on your file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date and time strings may have characters in them (like colons) that may not be legal characters for your file system.

Comment: Colons are illegal too?! aaaaaah that'll be it! *starts coding*
Cool :D The error message has now changed to `(filename): No such file or directory`

Comment: Got it :D had to change `fstream log` to `ofstream log` Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
   log.open(filename.c_str());
```

The `open` method requires a `char *`, a.k.a. a C-style string, not a C++ `std::string`.